# Why does $561$ divides $3^{561}-3$ if it doesn't divide $3$ nor $3^{560} -1$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

$561$ is a Carmicheal number.
I was asked in an exercise to prove that it is so by proving that  $561 | a^{561}-a$ for any integer a.

Now, if $561 | 3^{561}-3$    then $561|3*(3^{560}-1)$

But since $\gcd(561,3) > 1$  then it is false that $561 | 3^{560}-1$ (Isn't it?)

Then $561 | 3$ which is false.

Then by counterexample it would be false that $561 | a^{561}-a$ for any integer a.

What I am missing in the argument?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the definition of Carmichael numbers again: You only need to have it for all $a$ such that $gcd(561,a) = 1$, the others are excluded already in the definition.

Comment: The rule $p|ab\implies p| a $ or $p|b$ might not work if $p$ isn’t prime

Comment: @J.W.Tanner That's what I was missing! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dirk  no...for a [Carmichael Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) $N$, we have $a^N-a\equiv 0 \pmod N$ for all integers $a$.

Answer (score 5):

You have $561 = 3 \cdot 187$, so $561$ divides $3x$ iff $187$ divides $x$. You don't need another factor of 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try your argument with different numbers

> If $6 \mid 12$, then $6 \mid 3 \cdot 4$
>
> But since $\gcd(6,3) > 1$ then it is false that $6 \mid 4$ (Isn't it?)
>
> Then $6 \mid 3$ which is false.

Comment: I said "Since $gcd(561,3) > 1$ then it is false that $561 | 3^{560}-1$" because 561, as a Carmicheal number, only divides $a^{560}-1$ if gcd(a,561) = 1.

Comment: @Andrés Ok, but you can still see how $6 \mid 12$ but $6 \nmid 3$ or $4$. In general $n \mid ab$ implies $\frac{n}{\gcd(n,a)} \mid b$. $n$ only divides $b$ if $\gcd(n,a) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Divide by $3$ to  get $$561|3(3^{560}-1)\iff 187|(3^{560}-1)$$

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title question, note that [Euclid’s lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma) that $p|ab\implies p|a$ or $p|b$ works for prime numbers $p$, but $561$ isn’t prime.

(In fact, in abstract algebra, $p$ is prime is defined as $p|ab\implies p|a$ or $p|b$ .)